# Fixed points as a full subcategory of prefixed points?

Tags: category-theory, fixed-point-theorems

I'm working through [these notes](https://pure.tue.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/2401150/8930814.pdf), which cover some fixed point theory for categories.

Here, we encounter the following definitions (I've rephrased them):

> Let $C$ be a category and $F$ an endofunctor on $C$.
>
> - A *prefixed point* of $F$ is pair $(A, \alpha)$
>     where $A$ is an object of $C$ and $\alpha$ a morphism from
>     $F(A)$ to $A$;
> - a *fixed point* of $F$ is a prefixed point $(A, \alpha)$
>       where $\alpha$ is an isomorphism.

Then. the category **PFP** of prefixed points of $F$ is defined in the following way:

- its objects are the prefixed points of $F$;
- for each $(A,\alpha)$, $(B,\beta)$ in **PFP**, the morphism set from $A$ to $B$ contains exactly the arrows $f \in \hom(A,B)$ such that the diagram
  $$
    \begin{aligned}
  &F(A) &\xrightarrow{\alpha} &A \\
  F(f) &\downarrow & &\downarrow f\\
  &F(B) &\xrightarrow{\beta}  &B
    \end{aligned}
    $$
  commutes.

Can I then define the category **FP** of fixed points of $F$ as the full subcategory of **PFP** whose objects are the fixed points of $F$?

Comment: Why couldn't you?

Comment: To me, that's perfectly sound. However, in the linked notes another definition is given, so I thought there could be something wrong with the definition I've come up with.

Comment: Isn't it what they actually do? are you talking about the second point of Definition 2.20 on top of page 18 ?

Comment: And they wrote it later in that same page! Not paying attention can lead to this. Thank you! I'll delete the question in a few minutes. :-)

Comment: Please don't do it! I'm sure we can make it interesting by asking some more. There surely is a relation between prefixed points and coalgebras for a functor. This has been extensively addressed in Kelly's "...and so on" paper. Give a look at that! It can answer questions like: is $\bf PF$ co/reflective in $\bf PFP$? Is this co/reflection exact? Is there a limit process yielding (pre)fixed points? Grazie!

Comment: @Just_A_Man I fixed the broken link. Regarding your question, I have no clue why the authors chose to adhere to that notation.